# Laravel query slow to fetch data from database

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a Laravel API and a front-end that's built in Nuxt JS. On one of my front-end pages, I'm displaying a paginated list of applications *(customer data)* from one of my database tables, a request in made to my endpoint and the function `applications` goes and gets the data from the database in a paginated list.

The issue though, is it feels pretty slow considering that I'm not going much with the data, and my database table doesn't have that many columns.

The schema for my applications table is:

```php
Schema::create('applications', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('hash', 42)->index();
    $table->string('product_type')->nullable();
    $table->string('email')->nullable()->index();
    $table->date('birthday')->nullable()->index();
    $table->string('postcode')->nullable()->index();
    $table->string('mobile')->nullable()->index();
    $table->text('data');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->timestamp('verified_at')->nullable();
});
```

And the functions in question are:

```php
/**
 * Applications
 */
public function getApplications()
{

    $applications = Application::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                               ->paginate(25);

    foreach ($applications as $key => $applicant) {
      try {
        $applications[$key]['data'] = json_decode($applicant['data']);
      } catch (\Exception $e) { }
    }

    return $applications;

}

/**
 * All applications
 *
 * @param  Request  $request
 */
public function applications(Request $request)
{

    try {

      // daily graphs
      $applications = $this->getApplications();

      // not set or nothing to report
      if (!$applications) {
        return response()->json([
          'success' => false,
          'msg' => 'No applications found, check back in a few minutes',
        ], 422);
      }

      // return the response
      return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'msg' => 'Icicle applications',
        'applications' => $applications ?? null
      ], 200);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {

      // return default template
      return response()->json([
        'success' => false,
        'msg' => 'We were unable to load applications right now',
      ], 422);

    }

}
```

I've tried changing the `paginate` to a simple `get` and I've also tried running the same query via Tinker, I've further tried completely removing my `foreach` loop to see if that boosts performance.

It's taking **7 seconds** to fetch the data, of which I have 2 million records, I feel as if this should be much faster as it's a simple query, am I missing something in my query or the way I'm fetching data?

Comment: can you try without `orderBy`? Also use `simplePaginate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions

1. Index the 'created_at' column and remove other indices (if they are unnecessary).
2. Use simplePaginate() - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#simple-pagination
3. If you are using laravel 8, try cursor pagination - https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#cursor-pagination